# При переходе по роутам меняется адрес, по которому запрашиваются статические файлы (фавиконки), как с этим бороться?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, favicon

Для роутинга используется React Router 5, схема примерно такая (подробнее [здесь](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-waterfall-zzz92)):

```
<div className="App">
  <Header />
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
       <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page2} />
       <Redirect to="/page1" />
     </Switch>
   <Footer />
</div>
```

И почему-то при переходе по роутам меняется адрес, по которому запрашиваются статические файлы. Например, было: http://localhost:8080/icons/favicon.png , но после перехода по роуту на адрес http://localhost:8080/page1, фавиконку периодически пытается запрашивать уже с адреса http://localhost:8080/page1/icons/favicon.png, естественно, получая в ответ ошибку 404. Ошибки не критичные, но портят внешний вид консоли. Возможно, кто-нибудь может дать совет, как с этим бороться.

Comment: Используй полный путь до картинки. К примеру таким образом: <img src={window.location.origin + '/icons/favicon.png'} />

Comment: попробуйте указать base в хеде. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @an_parubets, подскажи пожалуйста, а как этот полный путь положить в запись вида <link rel="icon" type="image/png"  href="./icons/favicon.png"> ?

Comment: @RTW, спасибо, работает.

Comment: @Eeki принимайте ответ тогда :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хедере нужно указать [base href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp):

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

Все относительные пути будут считаться от него.